# Is there any way to add backgrounds in Blender 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

In 2.8, there is no background image option:

[image: Blender 2.79] [image: Blender 2.80]

I am aware of the alternatives like putting an image in a empty or the image directly to the camera. But is there like an addon or something I similar that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

It can be found in the camera's properties, but the behavior is still not correct.
[image]